# Does a method marshalled on the UI Thread need to be thread-safe

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

If I Invoke a method onto the UI Thread is it searilized by the Windows message queue and subsequently doesn't need to be re-entrant?

```
    private void CalledFromWorkerThread()
    {
        //changed from 'InvokeRequired' Anti-Pattern
        this.Invoke((Action) (() => _counter++; /* Is this ok? */ ));
    }
```

**Clarification: It is only the UI thread that will be accessing _counter.**

Comment: You should also use a lock on the counter if you are not already.

Comment: see also here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Comment: Testing `InvokeRequired` is an anti-pattern.  `Control.Invoke` already contains such a check.

Comment: @0A0D Mr Skeet doesn't use a lock in the Method that's been invoked in the aforementioned link? If it's only the UI thread that's accessing the `_counter` it's safe, that's my original question?

Comment: Yes, you are correct as long as it is the UI thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have is fine, assuming `_counter` is only accessed by the UI thread.

If two threads call your `CalledFromWorkerThread`, then _counter will be properly incremented and thread-safe with what you have.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the clarification, that only the UI thread is accessing _counter, you don't need a lock. I've updated my example. I prefer coding it this way to avoid the extra if invoke required check.

```
private void CalledFromWorkerThred()
{
    this.Invoke((Action) (() => _counter++; ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will delegate the call from the same thread, does not necessarily mean everything else you do in that function will be thread-safe.

Comment: Assume this is the only code that changes that field!  Is it thread safe?

Comment: Then its the only thread accessing it (so it does not need to be threadsafe). So, Yes it is safe.